# Shared printer deployed via Group Policy Preferences still trying to map printers even though the GPO is deleted. Why?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I created a GPO to map a printer via Group Policy Preferences with the Shared Printer user policy. I've since deleted the GPO, but whenever I log into any machine, it still tries to map the printer, but fails (since the queue doesn't exist on the server any more). The policy was set to `Create`. This even happens on machines that I have never logged into before.

What is causing this and how can I stop it from happening?

Comment: Do you see anything obvious in a `gpresults`?

Comment: @Zoredache Well this is embarrassing. Post this as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, let's nip this before it gets any more attention.

Check `gpresults` to make sure there's nothing obvious in there.  Maybe something (somehow) went wrong and the GPO is still being applied to the system.  Happens all the time, for various reasons (some of which are more embarrassing than others).